# Am I misusing Docker (nodejs app deploy)?

Tags: node.js, docker

Docker file (`.dockerignore` is not shown here, though it is present in the same directory):

```
FROM node:8 
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapplication
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm ci --only=production
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

...where `npm start` whould run `tslint` to fix code issues, `tsc` to compile TypeScript source code and finally `node` on the compiled `index.js` file that spins up an `express` server. Pretty standard configuration, yet it works fine.

But it feels like I am misusing Docker: why do I move not yet compiled code and compile it later, whereas I could compile it in prior? More than that, I must keep:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.8",
    "tslint": "^5.16.0"
  }
```

...those dependencies as both `devDependencises` and `dependencies` and compiler warns me about it.

I am not a Docker guy, not at all, so is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed a better way! Docker now has an ability called 'multi-stage images'. With this ability you can now copy the entire project into a Docker build context, build the project, then "reset" the container image to build a 'ready to run' production Docker image.

This has a number of advantages:

1. The build environment can be configured to match the execution
   environment...or not at all. Often times, and a motivator for the
   feature, was many projects require a load of dependencies to build.
   Yet in production very few are needed to run.
2. Reduces the deployed docker image. No need to have all those dev-dependencies in
   the deployed image.
3. Removed complexity in the Dockerfile of 'RUN install package A' then later 'RUN 
   uninstall package A' once the application is complied.

Here is the best place to get started with multi-stage images: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Hope this helps! Let me know how it turns out.